# How to restore the folder option in windows XP (which has been deleted by VIRUS !?)

Tags: windows-xp, windows-registry, virus

Because of a Brontok virus .. my explorer is not showing FOLDER OPTION in TOOLS menu .. Is there any Registry edition to fix this ?

By the way I tried GPEDIT (gpedit.msc using run) There also (as it is simple UI for average users) I couldn't fix the issue ..

Comment: Best option will be to format your PC cause as far as I have seen, Brontok does a lot of damage to the Operating System.

Comment: oops .. ohk .. I will see ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its done anyway ..

```
Go to Start, Run then type in regedit and click Ok.
Browse to the following key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer

Create a REGISTRY KEY with the name : NoFolderOptions
assign the vaule to 0.
Restart your computer.
```